# pygraphviz/networkx external label (xlabel)

Tags: networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz

I have a question regarding external labels in pygraphviz. Sadly, I haven't found anything regarding this on the internet.
I want to use networkx to create/parse a graph in tree structure and then use pygraphviz/pydot to draw it. I need external labels on top of the normal labels for the nodes because I want to display values for the nodes + the node name itself.
Let's say I have the following graph (very simplified example of what I'm doing later):

```
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([('A','B'), ('A','C')])
p = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot(g)
```

So I'm using the last line to generate a tree like hraph and I need external labels for B and C.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For pygraphviz you can pass through arbitrary graphviz attributes, so you can do:

```
dot.node('point', '', shape='point', xlabel='Label')
```